# sooner than possible vs as soon as possible

Tags: comparatives

I wonder if someone could help me. I always use "as soon as possible" but in many occasions I've also heard "sooner than possible", which I would never use because it seems quite weird to me. Am I wrong or could it also be acceptable?

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing this with 'sooner than later' vs 'sooner rather than later'? 'Sooner than possible' is something I've never heard, and could only be a tongue-in-cheek usage, and perhaps a statement that something is a pipe-dream  ('Kristol states “one expected no better of the Senate Democrats, who want to get out of Iraq as soon as possible, or sooner than possible').

Comment: Yes, I am. Since I've always used "as soon as possible" without thinking too much about it, I'd consider "sooner than possible" incorrect or, at least, a calque from another language and your answer seems to confirm my impression.

Answer (score 5):

"Sooner than possible" is, of course, impossible by definition.  I've never encountered this exact wording, but I've heard a similar expression, used jokingly:

"As soon as possible, if not sooner."

As I say, this is semi-serious and is done to communicate some extra urgency.

Behind it there is an implication that when the person being asked to do something does it "As soon as possible" then they are actually capable of doing it even faster, perhaps with an extra degree of personal sacrifice such as working extra hours, skipping lunch, dropping all other work, or something along those lines.

You should stick with "As soon as possible", anyway.

Comment: Of course, I'd never say that but I was puzzled because many people I know use that expression, although it seems completely wrong to me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

It's literally impossible to have something done sooner than possible. However, the root phrase might be the idiomatic *as soon as possible, if not sooner* (see [acronym finder](http://www.acronymfinder.com/As-Soon-As-Possible-If-Not-Sooner-%28ASAPINS%29.html) and [the free dictionary](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/As+Soon+As+Possible+If+Not+Sooner)). This idiom is intended to emphasise urgency, and is similar to [*I need it yesterday*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+need+it+yesterday).

Comment: I knew that it could be used in the idiomatic way you referred to but my doubt was about "sooner than possible" because I heard it from many people I know, even though I have never considered to say it and I think l'll never do it. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mind if i ask where you live?  Maybe it's a local idiom.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Which idiom are you referring to - "... sooner than possible", "... if not sooner", or "I need it yesterday"?

Comment: Sorry, i was referring to "Sooner than possible".